# PHP Multi-user Login with Session

Tags: php, session, authentication, multi-user

I have 7 user levels. I will be redirected depending on my input (for example I input the credentials of the admin, i will be redirected to admin page) and same goes with the other 6. The problem I have is that after successfully logging in, if I change the url from (localhost/admin/home.php) to (localhost/employee/home.php) I can now access the employee's page. I want to have restrictions on that. Or maybe an error that says "Unauthorized user. Access denied." something like that. Here's my code.

index.php

```
    <form action="checklog.php" method="POST">
     <h1>Log in</h1> 
      <p> 
       <label for="username" class="uname" > Your email or username </label>
       <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername " minlength="2" />
      </p>                          
      <p> 
       <label for="password" class="youpasswd"> Your password </label>
       <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" minlength="2" /> 
      </p>                          
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    <?php // To display Error messages
    if(isset($_GET['err'])){
    if ($_GET['err']==1){
    echo "Invalid Credentials.";}
    else if($_GET['err']==5){
    echo "Successfully Logged out";}
    else if ($_GET['err']==2){
    echo "You're trying to access an unauthorized page.";
    }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
```

checklog.php (This is where I process the credentials.)

```
    <?php
require_once("db.php");
function check_input($r){
    $r=trim($r);
    $r=strip_tags($r);
    $r=stripslashes($r);
    $r=htmlentities($r);
    $r=mysql_real_escape_string($r);
    return $r;
    }
if (isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){

    $u=check_input($_POST['username']);
    $p=md5(check_input($_POST['password']));
    try{
    $db=get_db();
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? && password=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($u,$p));
    $r=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($r){
        session_start();
        $access_level=$r['access_level'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$r['username'];
        $_SESSION['access_level']=$access_level;
        if ($access_level==0){
            header("Location: admin/home.php");
            }
         if($access_level==1){
            header("Location: user/home.php");
            }
           if($access_level==2){
              header("Location: businesshead/home.php");
              }
            if($access_level==3){
               header("Location: scm/home.php");
               }
             if($access_level==4){
                header("Location: finance/home.php");
                }
              if($access_level==5){
                 header("Location: gm/home.php");
                 }
               if($access_level==6){
                 header("Location: scma/home.php");
               }

        }
    else{
        header("Location:index.php?err=1");
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        die("Database error: ".$e->getMessage());
    }
}
else{
    header("Location:index.php");
    }
?>
```

And lets just assume that this is my admin page (admin.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

Welcome!

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if ($access_level==0){
            header("Location: admin/home.php");
}
"0" means FALSE That mean $access_level has no value

Comment: Actually it verifies the access level of the user. In my database, admin accounts have the access level of 0, users 1, and so on. So I think there's nothing wrong with that part. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check session on every page. Put related code on top of every page like

**admin page**

```
 <?php   
 session_start();
 if($_SESSION['type'] != 0){
        echo "Unauthorized user. Access denied."
        die; // stop further execution
 } ?>
```

**user page**

```
<?php   
 session_start();
 if($_SESSION['type'] != 1){
        echo "Unauthorized user. Access denied."
        die; // stop further execution
  } ?>
```

Comment: How about the index, do I need to have a session on that one? Because I tried to add that one on the admin page, and when I log in it only displays the "Unauthorized user. Access denied." message. :(

Comment: I have edited my answer check now. I have removed extra `=` from condition.  Which is for strict type

Answer (score -1):

use this one code in top of the all pages

```
 <?php   if($_SESSION['type']==1){
        header('index.php?msg=Admin Not Access This page');
  }?>
```

Comment: Does 'type' pertains to the access level?

Comment: you have add some type or role in user registration time so use it